# in Unix reading a beginning of a filename and inserting it to another file

Tags: unix

Could anybody tell me what is the best way to copy fragment of a filename, for example

axheMyfile.txt, read first 4 unique letters and copy that to a new tabdelimited file to be merged with another string.

I need to do that for tens of files.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In **bash** (and **ksh** as well, as I recall) parameter expansion allows substrings in the form **${param:offset:length}**. Try the following, and you will see how it works:-

```
fname=axheMyfile.txt
echo ${fname:0:4}
```

There are other expansions that allow for search-based substring extraction, eg `${fname%.*}` or `${fname%%.*}` will remove the **.txt** (there would be a difference if there were more than one dot in the name).